# Position fixed sidebar and centering content

Tags: html, css

I'm totally lost with css, can anyone help me out with centering and making responsive pictures in content area without hacking css ? That fixed sidebar makes it hard, because I cant use justify-content and align-items, because it will be hidden under sidebar.

Thanks

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="sidebar">
       <ul>
         <li>
           <span>Home</span>
        </li>
         <li>
           <span>Home</span>
         </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
      </div>
    </div>

    .container {
      padding-left:200px
    }

    .sidebar {
      position:fixed;
      height:100%;
      width:200px;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      background:#fff;
      border-right:2px solid;
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vum4d0j2/)

Comment: Display:block your content div and float it right. Id also strongly suggest giving both content and sidebar a percentage width. Then you can continue to use normal methods. (Assuming your container has a any width, i.e 100%)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to make the images centered, you can just add the rule

```
.content {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind the content div is currently overlapping the sidebar. The images will still look slightly offset to the left.

Comment: @Lewis The container is, the content is not because the sidebar has a width of 200px and the container has a padding-left of 200px

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox. You can still keep your sidebar without using `position: fixed;` by going `flex: 0 0 200px;` and to keep the heights different add an `align-items: flex-start;` to the container. Better yet put `align-self: flex-start;` on the `.container` to be more specific.

Check out full example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  height:100vh;
  width:200px;
  background:#fff;
  border-right:2px solid;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li><span>Home</span></li>
      <li><span>Home</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, but then my sidebar border height is aligned to content, i'd like the border to be max height ;/

Comment: Hey give it a shot now. If you want different heights just add align-items: flex-start; to the flex container. I put the height of the sidebar to 100vh as well